# SocketException: Broken pipe with a mysql database accessed through JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc, tomcat6

I have a web application with a MySQL backend accessed through JDBC. Every morning I see this exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

```
java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Broken pipe
```

STACKTRACE:

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2744)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1612)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
at com.model.dbchecks.DatabaseConnectHandler.db_execute_prepared_query(DatabaseConnectHandler.java:117)
at com.model.dbchecks.UserHandler.does_user_exist(UserHandler.java:154)
at com.model.dbchecks.UserHandler.authenticate_user(UserHandler.java:66)
at com.web.security.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
```

How do I prevent this ?

Comment: Every morning? Maybe could be TimeZone error :/

Answer (score 0):

according to the log `LoginServlet` is invoked and it calls the 
`com.model.dbchecks.DatabaseConnectHandler.does_user_exist()` which is causing the trouble.

Comment: There seems to be no issue with the function. I guess this is related to database connect timeout of a database connection which the function is using . Any insight into how this could be resolved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DaTaBomb Can you show us what that function does -- at least anonymized, in terms of how it's accessing the DB and using JDBC resources?